# randomForest in R runs out of memory far less than physical limit

Tags: r, linux, memory-management, random-forest

I am trying to run an R script that builds randomForests, and the script will die with a `"cannot allocate vector of size 549.4 Mb"` error.  I am running 64 bit R on a Google Cloud Engine linux instance with 8 cores and 7.2 GB Memory. I see other folks having trouble with the memory limits in R, but I don't understand why I am limited at so far below the physical allocation on the instance. A trace of the memory usage at the system level shows that the machine is not low on memory. The ulimit is set to unlimited for everything that looks important (output below). ***Question: how to increase the amount of memory R can allocate to vectors?***

The code is designed to test the scalability/time gains from using randomForest on parallel cores.  It works until the model needs to be fit with 6000 training examples, so I know the code functions for at least the inner most 2 loops. I've also tried adding explicit GC calls, and it the gcinfo output says I have ~50% remaining until I need to build the bigger model (with 6000 input points).

Code:

```
install.packages(c("randomForest", "doMC", "foreach", "dismo", "raster", "gbm", "SDMTools", "RMySQL", "rgdal", "gam", "earth"), repos='http://cran.mtu.edu/')
library(foreach)
library(raster)
library(dismo)
library(SDMTools)
library(parallel)
library(randomForest)
library(RMySQL)
library(doMC)

picea_points <- read.csv(paste(occPath, "picea_ready.csv", sep=""))

treeSeq <- seq(from=1000, to=11000, by=5000)
TexSeq <- seq(from=11000, to=11000, by =5000)
totalCores <- detectCores()
for (ncores in 3:totalCores){
  registerDoMC(cores = ncores)
  for (numTex in TexSeq){ ## change the number of training examples
    for (numTrees in treeSeq){ ## number of randomForest trees
      for (rep in 1:5){ ## replicate benchmarks
      ## Take a testing set
        t1 <- Sys.time()
        q <- nrow(picea_points)
        q_test <- 0.75*q
        testing_set <- picea_points[sample(q, q_test), ] ## select q_test random rows from points

        ## now take a random sampling on nocc rows
        training_set <- points[sample(q, numTex), ] ## this is what we will build the model upon
        training_set <- na.omit(training_set)
        x <- as.matrix(training_set[c('bio2', 'bio7', 'bio8', 'bio15', 'bio18', 'bio19')])
        y <- training_set[['presence']]
        model <- foreach(ntree=rep(numTrees, ncores), .combine=combine, .multicombine=TRUE,
                         .packages='randomForest') %dopar% {
                           randomForest(x, y, ntree=ntree)}

        t2 <- Sys.time()
        # save to database
        # ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`ulimit -a`:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 28716
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 28716
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

`R Info`

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
```

I have the error log and can post that too if it would be helpful.

[image: MemoryUsage]

Comment: R throws an error when a request for space is refused by the OS. So it is perfectly reasonable to expect that might occur when memory reaches 80% of maximum .... especially so when the maximum is less than 8GB. I'm guessing that a "cloud engine" does not have a virtual memory facility as might be available on a more full featured computer installation. My suggestion is that you contact the vendor who will, i expect, suggest more virtual RAM.

Comment: Just so you're clear, the object size reported in R's error message is simply the size of the specific request that triggered the refusal from the OS, not the total memory in ise by R.